# Unable to EFI boot after Ubuntu 12.10 install (Lenovo E30)

Tags: uefi, grub-efi

Basically the system won’t boot.  After the BIOS screen I get the message:
“Error 1692: No operating system found”

I ran the ‘boot-repair’ utility without success.  Here is the boot info that utility generated:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5695250/

Everything looks correct as far as I can tell.  I booted a liveCD, mounted /dev/sda1, and poked around the “EFI” directory.  Everything looks correct in there also.  Here is a pastebin for the commands I ran there:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5695339

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this situation?  I've been through all the options in the BIOS and nothing seems to help.
I noticed this message from 'boot-repair'

> "Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file"

However, I do not see any options in the BIOS startup for selecting which option to boot from.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command from a Linux EFI-mode emergency boot:

```
efibootmgr -o 3
```

Note that's a lowercase letter `-o` in the command.

If that doesn't work, then your firmware is broken, and I recommend the following:

1. Mount your ESP (`/dev/sda1`) somewhere convenient (say, `/boot/efi`).
2. `cd` to `/boot/efi/EFI`.
3. Type `sudo rm -r Microsoft`. (This assumes that you do *not* have a Windows installation on the computer. If I'm mistaken in this, then *do not* perform this step.)
4. Type `sudo mv boot boot-old`.
5. Type `sudo cp -a ubuntu boot`.
6. Type `sudo mv boot/grubx64.efi boot/bootx64.efi`.